# Add product field to cart opencart

Tags: opencart

In opencart, at success page, i need to check product's specific field value to take an action. Specifically field: stock_status_id.

WHen i use

```
$this->cart->getSubTotal()
```

and

```
$this->session->data['order_id']
```

i can get sku, name, category, price, quantity fields but when i try to get stock_status_id field using this code:

```
$product['stock_status_id']
```

i don't get anything. I opened system/library/cart.php file and added to data array stock_status_id with no success.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! Its in system/library/cart.php look for:

```
$this->data[$key] = array
```

and add a  line with the field you want to bring!